# How can I access ...pageProbs that I passed to a Component in _app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am loading a bunch of data at the loading of my site via getInitialProps.

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
// Calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
const globalLocale = await getGlobalData()

return {
  ...appProps,
  pageProps: {
    global: globalLocale,
  },
}
```

The return statement.

```
return (
        <>
        <Head>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href={getStrapiMedia(global.favicon.url)} />
        </Head>
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
        </>
    )
```

My question now is how I can access the pageProbs on a different page. For example I want to access the data I loaded in the _app.js on my index.js page.
However I am absolutely clueless how I can make use of them.

Cheers.

Comment: How familiar are you with React? The `pageProps` you pass to your page component in `_app` will be available as props in that same component. For instance, assuming your page component is `Home`, the `global` prop will be available at `export default function Home({ global }) { ... }`.

Comment: Okay I think I definitely need here some research. Could you provide me with a link to the doc where this is explained? Not sure how to google it.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the official React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering what I was actually looking for since it might be helpful:

The solution was actually quite simple.

As described I have a simple _app.js file looking like this:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

    // Extract the data we need
    const { global } = pageProps
    if (global == null) {
        return <p>404</p>
    }

    return (
       <>
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
       </>
    )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    // Calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
    const globalData = await getGlobalData()
  
    return {
      ...appProps,
      pageProps: {
        global: globalData,
      },
    }
  }

export default MyApp;
```

The goal of my question was to be able to access the ...pageProbs in my index.js file.

The solution after reading the docs was quite simple. I just needed to define the pageProbs as a parameter in my const IndexPage;

```
const IndexPage  = (pageProps) => {

    global = pageProps.global;

    return (
        <>
            <p>{global.id}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

simple as that. I do feel a little dumb now for asking it. Still was just not sure how to phrase my question, I think that was the biggest problem